# Breaks within Each and If statements not behaving quite how I want them to in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, if-statement, hash, break

In the following code, my expectation is that `:key2` or `:key5` would be assigned `"1"` due to the 2nd `elsif` statement, however it seems to be that my code instead runs the final `else` statement. Are my `break` statements not placed in the right locations?

Whenever this code is run I simply want it to replace one value and end.

```
hash = { :key1 => "3", :key2 => "3", :key3 => "3", :key4 => "3", :key5 => "3", :key6 => "3", :key7 => "3", :key8 => "2", :key9 => "3"}   

array = [[:key1, :key2, :key3], [:key4, :key5, :key6], [:key7, :key8, :key9], [:key1,         :key4, :key7], [:key2, :key5, :key8],[:key3, :key6, :key9], [:key1, :key5, :key9], [:key3, :key5, :key7]]
array.each do |x|
if hash.values_at(*x).count("1") == 2 and hash.values_at(*x).count("3") == 1
    x.each do |x|
        if hash[x] == "3"
            hash[x] = "1"
        break
        end

    end
    break

    elsif hash.values_at(*x).count("2") == 2 and hash.values_at(*x).count("3") == 1
        x.each do |e|
            if hash[e] == "3"
                hash[e] = "1"
            break
            end

        end
        break
     elsif hash.values_at(*x).count("1") == 1 and hash.values_at(*x).count("3") == 2
        x.each do |g|
            if hash[g] == "3"
                hash[g] = "1"
            break
            end
        end
        break
     elsif hash.values_at(*x).count("3") == 3
        x.each do |h|
            if hash[h] == "3"
                hash[h] = "1"
                break
            end
        end
        break

else

end
end
```

Comment: You need to look at how the `case` statement works. It appears you're trying to redesign how `if` works to behave similar to a `case`/`when`, or perhaps nested `case` statements.

Comment: You are also shadowing an outer variable on line 6, with the `x.each do |x|` which is not really the thing to do.

Comment: would `case` run them in order? I basically want them run in order and if one of the keys is changed to "1" then I want the loop to break @theTinMan

Comment: Yes, don't shadow variable names. With variable names that can be longer than a single character use some names that are more descriptive.

Comment: `case` will run them in the same order that `if` does. The logic starts at the top and falls through, checking the conditions as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code reorganized with better whitespace:

```
hash = {
  :key1 => "3",
  :key2 => "3",
  :key3 => "3",
  :key4 => "3",
  :key5 => "3",
  :key6 => "3",
  :key7 => "3",
  :key8 => "2",
  :key9 => "3"
}   

array = [
  [:key1, :key2, :key3],
  [:key4, :key5, :key6],
  [:key7, :key8, :key9],
  [:key1, :key4, :key7],
  [:key2, :key5, :key8],
  [:key3, :key6, :key9],
  [:key1, :key5, :key9],
  [:key3, :key5, :key7]
]

array.each do |key_set|

  if hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 2 and hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1

    key_set.each do |x|

      if hash[x] == "3"
        hash[x] = "1"
        break
      end

    end
    break

  elsif hash.values_at(*key_set).count("2") == 2 and hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1

    key_set.each do |e|

      if hash[e] == "3"
        hash[e] = "1"
        break
      end

    end
    break

  elsif hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 1 and hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 2

    key_set.each do |g|

      if hash[g] == "3"
        hash[g] = "1"
        break
      end

    end
    break

  elsif hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 3

    key_set.each do |h|

      if hash[h] == "3"
        hash[h] = "1"
        break
      end

    end
    break

  else

  end

end
```

And here it is with the variable names improved, and `and` replaced with `&&` plus some parenthesis to visually show the logic groups in your conditionals:

```
array.each do |key_set|

  case
  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 2) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1)

    key_set.each do |_key|

      if hash[_key] == "3"
        hash[_key] = "1"
        break
      end

    end
    break

  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("2") == 2) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1)

    key_set.each do |_key|

      if hash[_key] == "3"
        hash[_key] = "1"
        break
      end

    end
    break

  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 1) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 2)

    key_set.each do |_key|

      if hash[_key] == "3"
        hash[_key] = "1"
        break
      end

    end
    break

  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 3)

    key_set.each do |_key|

      if hash[_key] == "3"
        hash[_key] = "1"
        break
      end

    end
    break

  else

  end

end
```

There is a huge amount of redundancy and lack of "DRYness". "DRY" stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself" which means reduce your repetitious code.

```
_key = key_set.find{ |k| hash[k] == '3' }
hash[_key] = '1' if _key
break
```

looks like a reasonable replacement for:

```
    key_set.each do |_key|

      if hash[_key] == "3"
        hash[_key] = "1"
        break
      end

    end
    break
```

so substituting that in reduces the code to:

```
array.each do |key_set|

  case
  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 2) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1)

    _key = key_set.find{ |k| hash[k] == '3' }
    hash[_key] = '1' if _key
    break

  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("2") == 2) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1)

    _key = key_set.find{ |k| hash[k] == '3' }
    hash[_key] = '1' if _key
    break

  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 1) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 2)

    _key = key_set.find{ |k| hash[k] == '3' }
    hash[_key] = '1' if _key
    break

  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 3)

    _key = key_set.find{ |k| hash[k] == '3' }
    hash[_key] = '1' if _key
    break

  else

  end

end
```

Each `when` is redundant, so they can be moved above the `case`:

```
array.each do |key_set|

  _key = key_set.find{ |k| hash[k] == '3' }
  hash[_key] = '1' if _key

  case
  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 2) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1)
    break

  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("2") == 2) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1)
    break

  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 1) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 2)
    break

  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 3)
    break

  else

  end

end

puts hash
```

A bit more reduction results in:

```
array.each do |key_set|

  _key = key_set.find{ |k| hash[k] == '3' }
  hash[_key] = '1' if _key

  case
  when (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 2) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1), 
      (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("2") == 2) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 1),
      (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("1") == 1) && (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 2),
      (hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 3)
    break

  else

  end

end

puts hash
```

Which, like all the others, outputs:

```
{:key1=>"1", :key2=>"3", :key3=>"3", :key4=>"3", :key5=>"3", :key6=>"3", :key7=>"3", :key8=>"2", :key9=>"3"}
```

That's a lot of code in the first one to do what the last one does. And, there's even more DRYing that can be done, but I'll leave it to you to figure it out.

Comment: thank you, I added a `puts` to the 2nd `when` and changed key8 to "1" expecting my `puts` however I received the `puts` I included in the final `when`. EDIT: I will review my code until it performs optimally.

Comment: @RavensFlock - there's only one `when` in @TimMan's reduced code. what are you referring to when you say "final when"?

Comment: After looking over this, I understand where I messed up but how would I do this so it iterates through all the arrays `key_set` and only finally performs `(hash.values_at(*key_set).count("3") == 3)` and the following code if none of the arrays can meet any of the previous cases. @the-tin-man @petet-alfivin

Answer (score 0):

There are no values other than `"3"` in your hash, so none of your conditionals will initially succeed except the last `elsif`, since they all require the presence of values other than `"3"`. In the body of the last `elsif`, you redefine `hash[key1]` to be `"1"`, but then you `break` out of that inner `each` and then `break` out of the outer each, terminating execution.  Nothing else happens.

Comment: Sorry, :key8 was supposed to be "2". When I run it however :key1 is always set to "1"

Comment: No matter. That still only gives you one "2", not two as your conditional requires, so the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 0):

That's some... Interesting code.  I definitely recommend simplifying to help debugging, but here's what's happening.

1. Enters `array.each`
2. `elsif hash.values_at(*x).count("3") == 3` hits
3. You play w/the hash a bit, and break out
4. You break out of `array.each`
5. Done.

Baby steps, and `puts` calls are your friend here.

Comment: I am just learning to code so I know it's not the best written. I was hoping once I got it to work that I could refractor.